# Saving jmeter report per each run and then restarting

Tags: graph, report, jmeter, aggregate

Just using JMeter for the first time so know very little, but I created a test plan to do some stress testing on a server.

The value I'm varying every time is the number of messages I send, increasing by 10 each run. I was told to use a text file with "10,20,30,40, etc" and then read in from it rather than making multiple thread groups and copying same code into it and replacing # of messages to send to 20,30, etc.

Now I want to save the values in Aggregate Report to a file per number, so the output would have at 10 this is aggregate report, 20 aggregate report, etc.

Is there a simple way to do this? Right now it seems aggregate report is just that, all of the data combined, not starting fresh every time. Is there a good command line way of doing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It as simple as follows:

Use a JMeter Property, something like "messagesnumber".

In JMeter GUI amend "Filename" of your Aggregate Report to use "messagesnumber" property as follows:

```
${__property(messagesnumber,,)}-messages
```

[__property()](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) is a JMeter function, which accesses any JMeter Property, in this case - "messagesnumber"

You can set a JMeter Property via `-J` command line switch

```
-JXXXX=YYYY
```

where `XXXX` - property name and `YYYY` - property value.

Following JMeter invokation (assuming that you're in /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter -Jmessagesnumber=10 -n -t messages.jmx -l messages.jtl
```

will set "messagesnumber" property to "10" and as the result "10-messages" aggregate report output will be produced in /bin folder.